# Is there a reason why Python 3 doesn't show the changed __name__ attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I didn't know Python 3 has made such change.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> def f():
    pass

>>> f.__name__ = 'g'
>>> f
<function g at 0x000000000264C6D8>
```

While in Python 3:

```
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:06:53) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]   on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> def f():
    pass

>>> f.__name__ = 'g'
>>> f
<function f at 0x0000000003335AE8>
```

What's the reason to do so? Am I missing anything?

Comment: please don't post screenshots of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `__qualname__` instead:

```
>>> def f():
...     pass
...
>>> f.__qualname__ = 'g'
>>> f
<function g at 0x0000000002AE5C80>
```

According to [PEP 3155 -- Qualified name for classes and functions - Proposal](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/#proposal):

> The `repr()` and `str()` of functions and classes is modified to use
>   `__qualname__` rather than `__name__`.

See also: [What's New in Python 3.3 - PEP 3155: Qualified name for classes and functions](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-3155-qualified-name-for-classes-and-functions).